# HTTP requests - how to?

Tags: java, android, sql, http, httprequest

I am trying to write an app to upload data to a online database but it seems that the app crashed. Could any one help me? Many thanks.

I think that the problem mainly occurs in the submitaction method.
I tried according to some online tutorials.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //A1 spinner ..
        //A2 spinner ..
        //A3 spinner ..


        Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                submitaction();

            }
        });

}//onCreate

private String submitaction(){

    String food = A1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String drink = A2.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String stuid = A3.getSelectedItem().toString();

    final String url = "felixwongsite.com/android/include.php";

    HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(url);
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("food", food));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("drink", drink));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stuid", stuid));

    try{

        httpRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpRequest);

        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {

            String strResult = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

            return strResult;
        }

    }catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }  return null;

}//submitaction()

}//MainActivity
```

Comment: _"I think that the problem mainly occurs in the submitaction method."_ If your app crashed you should have a stacktrace from logcat, so you should A) go through that stacktrace yourself, and B) include it in your question.

Comment: add your Logcat

Comment: You cant perform a networking operation in the main thread..Use `AsyncTask` to perform networking tasks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all network operations are not allowed on main thread.

```
"To avoid creating an unresponsive UI, don't perform network operations on the UI thread. By default, Android 3.0 (API level 11) and higher requires you to perform network operations on a thread other than the main UI thread; if you don't, a NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown."
```

see here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Solutions

1.you could implement asynctask to make network calls in background thread.

It would be a good idea to follow tutorals, eg.
 https://androidkennel.org/android-networking-tutorial-with-asynctask/

2.Or you could use some third party library like **retrofit**
 and here is the site http://www.baeldung.com/retrofit

hope this help.